Não consigo invalidar minha query usando o invalidateQueries do vue tanstack
O problema é o seguinte, estou fazendo um update em uma entidade do meu bando de dados, e o update ocorre, porque se eu recarregar a pagina a entidade vai estar atualizada, ou se eu sair entrar de uma rota para a outra o vue query vai invalidar como deveria, mas ele deveria fazer isso após realizer o update sem sair de uma rota para a outra.
O codigo onde atualizo a entidade no meu banco de dados e tento invalidar a query do vue query passando o keyComment, usando a função updateComment
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button'
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/dialog'
import DialogFooter from '@/components/ui/dialog/DialogFooter.vue'
import { useForm } from 'vee-validate'

import {
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from '@/components/ui/form'

import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input'
import { Textarea } from '@/components/ui/textarea'
import { updateCommentSchemaToTyped, UpdateCommentRequest } from '@/types'
import { keyComment, updateComment } from '@/http'
import { LoaderCircle } from 'lucide-vue-next'
import { useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/vue-query'
import { useAuth } from '@/contexts/use-auth'

interface UpdateCommentProps {
  commentUpdate: UpdateCommentRequest
}
const { handleSubmit, resetForm, isSubmitting } = useForm({
  validationSchema: updateCommentSchemaToTyped,
})

const queryClient = useQueryClient()

const { user } = useAuth()

const props = defineProps<UpdateCommentProps>()

const handleUpdateComment = handleSubmit(async (values) => {
  if (!user.value?.data.userId) return

  if (props.commentUpdate.userId !== user.value.data.userId) return

  await updateComment({
    title: values.title,
    content: values.content,
    userId: props.commentUpdate.userId,
    commentId: props.commentUpdate.commentId,
  })
  await queryClient.invalidateQueries({
    queryKey: [keyComment],
  })

  resetForm()
})
</script>

<template>
  <Dialog>
    <DialogTrigger as-child>
      <Button> Update </Button>
    </DialogTrigger>
    <DialogContent
      class="sm:max-w-[425px] bg-foreground ring-2 ring-primary-foreground/25"
    >
      <DialogHeader>
        <DialogTitle>Editar </DialogTitle>
        <DialogDescription>
          Você pode editar o seu comentário aqui.
        </DialogDescription>
      </DialogHeader>
      <form
        @submit="handleUpdateComment"
        class="w-full max-w-[600px] flex flex-col justify-center gap-2"
      >
        <FormField v-slot="{ componentField }" name="title">
          <FormItem>
            <FormLabel>Titulo</FormLabel>
            <FormControl>
              <Input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Titulo do comentário"
                v-bind="componentField"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormMessage />
          </FormItem>
        </FormField>
        <FormField v-slot="{ componentField }" name="content">
          <FormItem>
            <FormLabel>Comentário</FormLabel>
            <FormControl>
              <Textarea
                type="text"
                placeholder="Seu comentário"
                v-bind="componentField"
                class="h-32 sizing"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormMessage />
            <FormDescription> No que você está pensando? ‍↔️ </FormDescription>
          </FormItem>
        </FormField>

        <DialogFooter class="gap-2">
          <Button
            type="submit"
            variant="secondary"
            class="flex items-center justify-center"
            :disabled="isSubmitting"
          >
            <LoaderCircle class="w-6 h-6 animate-spin" v-if="isSubmitting" />

            <span class="flex items-center justify-center gap-2" v-else
              >Enviar <span>✔️</span></span
            >
          </Button>
          <Button type="button" variant="secondary" :onclick="resetForm">
            Reset
          </Button>
        </DialogFooter>
      </form>
    </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>
</template>

Devs ja tentei de tudo e mais um pouco, é somente aqui que ele não invalida as informações, porque eu tenho outras partes no meu codigo como o create e delete, e eles invalidam essa query passando a chave keyComment. Deveria ser algo simples de acordo com a doc do tanstack, mas eu acabei travando nessa parte.
Lembrando que o delete e o update ficam no mesmo lugar, mas o update não invalida as informações como deveria.

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
